# Using python3 to show bigrams of a (tokenized) text results in a broken pipe error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

My code:

```
import sys

def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

def main():

    bigrams = {}

    for line in sys.stdin:

        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split()

        for i in range (len(words)-1):

            bigram = (words[i],words[i+1])
            bigrams[bigram] = bigrams.get(bigram,0) + 1

    bigrams = list(bigrams.items())
    bigrams.sort(key=byFreq, reverse=True)

    for i in range(len(bigrams)):
        bg, count = bigrams[i]
        print("{0:<15}{1:<15}{2:>5}" .format(bg[0], bg[1], count))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would like to be able to use my python3 file with the command line, eg. `cat myfile.txt | python3 bigrams.py | head -5`

Executing my file like this results in the following output (using MacOS terminal):

```
van            de                25
in             de                14
aan            de                10
in             het                9
de             regering           9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bigram.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "bigram.py", line 33, in main
    print("{0:<15}{1:<15}{2:>5}" .format(bg[0], bg[1], count))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

It indeed prints 5 lines, but also a broken pipe error. This can be solved using the following:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

However, this does not seem like a good way to get rid of the error. Is there any other (better) way to do so?

Also, is there any better way to get the bigrams as output?

Hope anyone can help me out.

Cheers, Thijmen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, and only then `head` the top lines:

```
cat myfile.txt | python3 bigrams.py 2>&1 | head -5
```

I would suggest to pass the input filename and the number of (top) lines to print to the standard out as command line arguments instead:

```
def main():
    bigrams = {}
    #pass input filename as the first argument
    ifilename = sys.argv[1]  
    lines = open(ifilename,"r").readlines()
    #pass number of lines to print as a second argument 
    show_top_n = int(sys.argv[2])

    for line in lines:
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split()

        for i in range (len(words)-1):
            bigram = (words[i],words[i+1])
            bigrams[bigram] = bigrams.get(bigram,0) + 1

    bigrams = list(bigrams.items())
    bigrams.sort(key=byFreq, reverse=True)

    for i in range(show_top_n):
        bg, count = bigrams[i]
        print("{0:<15}{1:<15}{2:>5}" .format(bg[0], bg[1], count))
```

You would launch it like this:

`python bigrams.py myfile.txt 5`

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a solution, but for the sake of this question, I would really like to know if it is possible to get rid of the error without using command line arguments. How about the signal 'solution' in my OP - do you have any comments whether this is good or bad?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I thought your question was more about working with text